# How to send an array items from UI to MVC Controller

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an array of objects in UI that is being sent to MVC Controller . The Array of objects look like :

```
`DoorId`,`DoorName` and an array of `Schedules`. `Schedules` array has `ScheduleId` and `ScheduleName`.
```

[image]

Now how to send it to MVC Controller ? So that , every `DoorId` and it's associated `ScheduleId` can be extracted separately to form another obeject ?

Presently , I am sending the `DoorId` Array and the `ScheduleId` array separately ,

**But I do not want to do that . I want to send the entire array itself.**

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> AddGroup(string[] DoorIds, string[] scheduleEntity)//AccessGroupEntity entity, string accountId
    {
        GroupEntity groupEntity = new GroupEntity();


        var doorScheduleList = new List<DoorInfoEntity>();

        for(int i=0;i< DoorIds.Length;i++)
        {
            doorScheduleList.Add(new DoorInfoEntity()
            {
                DoorId = DoorIds[i],
                ScheduleId = scheduleEntity[i]

            });
        }

        accessGroupEntity.DoorItems = doorScheduleList;
```

And then Parse it as `Doors[index].DoorId` and `Doors[index].ScheduleId` to form 'DoorInfoEntity` object.

How to do it ?

I tried `object[] Doors` but it says `Object does not contain a definition for DoorId or ScheduleId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an object graph in C# that the modelbinder can bind the posted data to which mimics the object graph you have in your JavaScript. For example:

```
public class Door
{
    public Guid DoorId { get; set; }
    public string DoorName { get; set; }
    public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Schedule
{
    public Guid ScheduleId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then, you accept the root class as a param in your action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddGroup(List<Door> doors)
```

The modelbinder, then, will create the object graph server-side from the posted data.